# Mongo db transaction not rolling back spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-transactions

We have a mongo server hosted on mongo atlas . It is a M3 replica set and all the testing in done on the replica set only.

```
My app configuration is as follows.

public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
        String userName = env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.username");
        String password = env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.password");
        String authDatabase = env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database");
        
        String uriString = env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.uri");

        
        uri  = new ConnectionString(uriString);
        
        
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, authDatabase, password.toCharArray());
        return MongoClients
                .create(MongoClientSettings.builder().credential(credential).applyConnectionString(uri).build());
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        String database = env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.database");
        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), database);
        MappingMongoConverter mongoMapping = (MappingMongoConverter) template.getConverter();
        mongoMapping.afterPropertiesSet();
        template.setSessionSynchronization(SessionSynchronization.ALWAYS); 
        return template;
    }

    public @Bean MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }
```

Now when we intiating a multi document transaction it is not rolling back .

```
@Transactional
public void createMultiDocument {
  flag =true;
  template.save1(doc1);
  template.save2(doc2);
  if(flag) {
     throw new RuntimeException();
  }
  template.save3(doc3);  
}
```

In the above operation document1 and document2 are saving to the database.

Comment: WE are using spring boot 2.7.0 in the above set up

Answer (score 0):

Sorry false alarm.
We are throwing a checked exception which does not ensure a rollback.